# Socket Programming able get response from telnet but not c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I am able to connect server through telnet and receive a response through telnet but if I do same through my code I am not able to get that.
I am very sure that my code is right as I already tested it by creating client and server on my local.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ClientSocket
{
    public partial class Client : Form
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream; 

        public Client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            msg("Client Started");
            //clientSocket.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ip"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]));
            clientSocket.Connect("172.29.29.6", 7506);
            label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";
        }

        public void msg(string mesg)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage.Text);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            byte[] inStream = new byte[1000768];
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            //serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, 1000768);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            msg("Data from Server : " + returndata);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember that in C I had problems with that, usually solves filling the stream with end of string character (`'\0'`).

Comment: I guess not working means an Exception gets thrown? In this case what does it say?

Comment: "i am very sure that my code is right" It is obviously not right.

Comment: sir just to let u know... i created client and server both on local i sent a message and i recieved a reponse immediately... but when i am trying to consume somebody elses client it gets hang on serverStream.Read line... 
if i do same through telnet it works...
Procedures i did for telnet are as follows
1. telnet 192.142.23.13 3423
2. paste sending message
3. press ctrl+s to receive a response.
through telnet  i m recieving reponse but through c# code i am not.
i really dont understand what went wrong here...

Answer (score 1):

In telnet the data is sent as you type, but you only receive a response after hitting the *enter* key. I bet `txtMessage.Text` does not contain a newline or other termination of the message.

Comment: in telnet if i type ctrl+s it gives me response.
from my application i even tried sending ^s at the end of my text
ex. message^s
even this is not working. please help.

Comment: Have you tried adding CRLF (`"\r\n"`) to the text? I don't know what your server is expecting.

Comment: what is crlf for ctrl+s key

Comment: I don't understand your comment but I think you also don't understand mine. Did you try this: `byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage.Text + "\r\n");`?

Answer (score 0):

`Read` can return any number of bytes. The return value signals how many were read. It will not necessarily read all bytes at once. You need to read in a loop until all bytes have been read.